# MySQL create view joining two tables

Tags: mysql, join, view

How can I create a view that merges different columns with a different table? I have three tables for example: users, items and gifts (in this example it's a system that a user can give a gift to another user)

`users` table has information about users, `items` table has information about items and `gifts` table shows which user sent what gift to which user.

What I want is to create a view like following:

```
user_from | user_to | gift_name  | gift_price
sally     | john    | Teddy Bear | 10
```

Comment: I couldn't add images to question, so they are here:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/YCfAO.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/7AUhc.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/8W06W.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/forWs.png

Comment: What is the problem? The query part (ie how to fetch that data from those tables), or how to create a view in MySQL?

Comment: @th0th check my answer below. hope it helps.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You must join the three tables first. Example

```
CREATE VIEW GiftsList
AS
SELECT  b.name user_from,
        c.name user_to,
        d.name gift_name,
        d.price gift_price
FROM    gift a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.user_from = b.id
        INNER JOIN users c
            ON a.user_from = c.id
        INNER JOIN items d
            ON a.item = d.id
```

Comment: Changed `FROM gift a` to `FROM gifts a`, thought there was a typo. And I get error:
`#1054 - Unknown column 'b.users' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @th0th it's really a typo, it should be `a.user_from = b.id` and `a.user_from = c.id`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a view with two tables like:

```
 CREATE VIEW giftList AS
 SELECT users.user_from,users.user_to,gifts.gift_name,gifts.gift_price FROM users,gifts
 WHERE users.user_id = gifts.user_id;
```

The where clause is to make sure the output does not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I believe were looking for [data blending](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420?hl=en). So basically having google data studio do a JOIN statement on ids from 2 data sets