# How do i create a view that is made from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have three tables

```
Students (sid:integer, sname:string, age:integer) 
Courses (cid:integer, cname:integer, credits:integer) 
Grades(sid:integer, cid:integer, grade:string)
```

i am trying to create a view that lists the top students in the class using their  GPA

i have so far tried this query

```
CREATE VIEW TopStudents AS
SELECT Students.sid, Students.sname, AVG(Grades.grade) AS GPA
FROM Students, Grades
               INNER JOIN Grades ON Students.sid = Grades.sid
               INNER JOIN Grades ON Course.cid = Grades.cid
WHERE GPA >3.0
```

the trouble is i don't know the correct syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL create view joining two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352048/mysql-create-view-joining-two-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need    the proper join for the select

```
    CREATE VIEW TopStudents AS
    SELECT Students.sid, Students.sname, AVG(Grades.grade) AS GPA
    FROM Grades
    INNER JOIN Students ON Student.cid = Grades.sid
    INNER JOIN Course  ON Course.id = Grades.cid
```

Your main table is the  Grades table because is related to the other two. So from this table using a join for each table you need  the correct ON clause

(In your code you have several wrong part. You mix from clause with comma separated table name and join .. instead of join the two table to the course table you use tw time a join on grades  table but this syntax don't resolve the relation between the tables in the correct way).

Comment: Your spelling is still rather careless, and it is getting quite tiresome correcting it.